# NextGEN Gallery Album Sort Order

Tags: wordpress, nextgen-gallery

I am using the NextGEN plugin in WordPress to display a thumbnail for each gallery in an album. However, it seems that the gallery order that I specify in the album is only preserved if there are 5 or fewer galleries in the album. When there are more than 5 galleries in the album, the thumbnails display in a consistent but wrong order. Adding a 7th gallery shuffles them again, etc.

I looked in the database for the order but it is too cryptic, e.g., WyI2IiwiNSIsIjQiLCIzIiwiMiIsIjEiXQ==

This is the shortcode that I am using:

```
[ngg_images album_ids="9" display_type="photocrati-nextgen_basic_compact_album" thumbnail_height="300" thumbnail_width="300" thumbnail_crop="1" override_thumbnail_settings="1"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately it is buried deep, and no really useful answer can be found on the web, except for the following thread, which finally helped me:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/album-sort-order

- Go to: Other Options > Image Options > Default Sorting Method
- Change it to "Custom"
- Go to: Manage Albums
- If you now change the gallery order and save the album, the change will be respected

Comment: Wow. That seems to have done it. Almost obvious now that I know that's an option.

Answer (score 0):

That didn't work for me, but deleting the gallery from the page and reinserting it did as per. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-sort-order-not-working

Comment: link only answers should be avoided as the link can change over time. Summarize the info in the link in your answer.